# How to set category to a site in multistore in Magento

Tags: magento

I Have 3 sites in my magento installation and among them 2 sites are multistores and one is the root. I would like to set one particular category for a site in this. I have set the products accordingly to display in this store. But the problem is, currently all the other categories also are being shown in the menu which I don't want.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: you can select different root category menu based on store wise in edit store under store management

Comment: The problem is I can have only one root category and all the products from one category should be available across the platforms ofcourse as I make products I will tell which products should appear in which sotres. So I cannot simply create different root categories right? or can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look @ [Creating and assigning root categories](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories)

1. In System > Manage Stores, click the Store Name which will use the new Root Category.
2. From the “Root Category” drop down, choose the Root Category you just created.
3. Click “(✓) Save Store”

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have only one root category and you want to assign sub-categories to other store views.

All categories are active in all store by default. You have to deactivate the category that are not be shown for particular store. To do so, follow the steps below:

1. Admin -> Catalog -> Manage Categories
2. On the left column, you have option to choose different Store View. Select a store view (under Choose Store View)
3. Click on each sub-category and see on right column (main content area). Under the "General Information Tab", set Is Active = No. And, Save Category.

In case, if you have multiple root category do as R.S suggested. Remember when you have multiple root, you can not share products/category in different store view.